# Trying to build dynamic lambda expression to select based on property

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, lambda, expression

Trying to build a dynamic Lambda expression to select based on a user-supplied property name but getting the error "Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration".  I'm trying to get to this: `() => myObj.propName`

Here's the latest version of my code:

```
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(myObjType), propName);
    MemberExpression exp = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propName);
    var func = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(exp, parameter).Compile();
```

Error happens on the last line.  I've seen a few similar things on SO and elsewhere that have gotten me this far, but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  For now, all the properties I'm trying to work with are strings.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean `myObj => myObj.propName`? It's unclear whether you're really after a `Func<Foo, string>` or a `Func<string>` (in the latter case, where do you expect to get `myObj` from?)

Comment: Now we're moving beyond my understanding of Linq.  I'm trying to pass `func` into a method from a third-party library that has the following signature: `ThirdPartyMethod<T>(Func<T> func)`.  If I don't try to build the expression dynamically, I just hardcode it as `()=>myObj.PropName`.  If it helps, the 3rd party library is TypeMock Isolator and I'm trying to create a dynamic instance of this line: `Isolate.WhenCalled(() => myObj.PropName).WillReturn(fakeValue);` Thanks @jonskeet

Comment: Well with the lambda expression of `() => myObj.PropName`, there are no parameters - so where is `myObj` declared?

Comment: Yeah...definitely beyond my understanding of Linq now...  ;-)  Here's a more complete example of the code I'm trying to make dynamic: 

        var fakeObj = FakeNextInstanceOf<MyObj>();
        Isolate.WhenCalled(() => fakeObj.MyProp).WillReturn("ddd");

Does that help?  Really appreciate you sticking with me on this.  I'm trying to learn more Linq and have jumped into the deep-end here.

Comment: It's really not LINQ-specific. Do you understand that `() => myObj.PropName` has no parameters? This is just lambda expressions... the bit before the `=>` is the list of parameters, and here there's an empty list...

Comment: Yes, I get that much (no params), not sure where that comes into play here.

Answer (score 0):

To query with dynamic expression (as string), you can use [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) by Scott Gu of Microsoft.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14067998/649524) answer for detail.

The [Dynamic Linq library](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) abstracts the complex looking Expression.* calls into simple Linq Syntax that accepts Property Name as `string`.