# How to filter list of classes by property name?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I want to filter a collection of classes by the property name as a string. Let's say I have a class named Person, and I have a collection of it, either IEnumerable, or List, and I want to filter this collection, but I don't know the exact filter, I mean I can't use:

```
person.Where(x => x.Id == 1);
```

Let me give an example.

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int YearOfBorn {get; set;}    
}
```

And now I create a collection like:

```
List<Person> p = new List<Person>();
```

Now I want to filter everyone whose name is Alex, but I want to filter it using this function:

```
public List<Person> Filter(string propertyName, string filterValue, List<Person> persons)
```

So how I can filter it if I want to use Linq, or Lambda?

Thanks

Comment: Why can't you use `Where` ?

Comment: are you asking us to write the entire code for you?

Comment: I know I can use Func to do that, but I don't know how? And I know I have to somehow find the type of the property, and again I don't how when it is a list of classes.

Comment: If you want to have a method like the one you describe, as in pass along the parameter both the property, and the property value, you'll have to use reflection. but why would you want to do that? Are you trying to do something like converting SQL queries to linq?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filtering on template list with property name as string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067399/filtering-on-template-list-with-property-name-as-string)

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20386766/5174469) should also be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you can try using *Reflection*:

```
using System.Reflection;

... 

// T, IEnumerable<T> - let's generalize it a bit
public List<T> Filter<T>(string propertyName, string filterValue, IEnumerable<T> persons) {
  if (null == persons)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("persons");
  else if (null == propertyName)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("propertyName");

  PropertyInfo info = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

  if (null == info)
    throw new ArgumentException($"Property {propertyName} hasn't been found.", 
                                 "propertyName");

  // A bit complex, but in general case we have to think of
  //   1. GetValue can be expensive, that's why we ensure it calls just once
  //   2. GetValue as well as filterValue can be null
  return persons
    .Select(item => new {
      value = item,
      prop = info.GetValue(item),
    })
    .Where(item => null == filterValue
       ? item.prop == null
       : item.prop != null && string.Equals(filterValue, item.prop.ToString()))
    .Select(item => item.value)
    .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I used it wrong. Thanks. This line helped me a lot.
typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);

Comment: @Amir: you are welcome! Time to time *Reflection* helps us out, but be careful: it can be slow.